# printf() results in gibberish

Tags: c, embedded, printf, keil, c51

I have this code:

```
unsigned char *command = "0000";
unsigned char foo = (hex_char_to_int(command[0]) << 4) | hex_char_to_int(command[1]);
unsigned char bar = (hex_char_to_int(command[2]) << 4) | hex_char_to_int(command[3]);
printf("foo: %02x, bar: %02x\r\n", foo, bar);
```

It uses this function:

```
unsigned char hex_char_to_int(unsigned char ch) {
    switch (ch){
        case '0': return 0;
        case '1': return 1;
        case '2': return 2;
        case '3': return 3;
        case '4': return 4;
        case '5': return 5;
        case '6': return 6;
        case '7': return 7;
        case '8': return 8;
        case '9': return 9;
        case 'A': return 0xA;
        case 'B': return 0xB;
        case 'C': return 0xC;
        case 'D': return 0xD;
        case 'E': return 0xE;
        case 'F': return 0xF;
        case 'a': return 0xA;
        case 'b': return 0xB;
        case 'c': return 0xC;
        case 'd': return 0xD;
        case 'e': return 0xE;
        case 'f': return 0xF;
        default: return 0;
    }
}
```

This is the result:

```
"JW\xd6\x96'$$LK\x90\xbbar: 3030\r\r\n"
```

This is on the Keil C51 compiler, on an AT89C55WD, with `printf()` going over a serial port.

**What is going on?**

**EDIT**

I change the printf line to

```
printf("%02x%02x\r\n", (unsigned int)foo, (unsigned int)bar);
```

So it looks like a bug in `printf`. Please, programmers, never make a debugging tool that lies. I beg you.

Comment: There's no semi colon after command in your example so I'm not sure this would even compile. There's also an overflow `command[4]` is not in `command` max index is 3.

Comment: Is this the exact sequence of code that is being used (values inside them aside)? This does not seem like it should lead to a problem.

Comment: Also check that non formatted strings print correctly to the serial console.

Comment: No I've sanitized the code to remove anything that could identify it. @JesusRamos yes, other strings print correctly, and other format specifies even work correctly depending on the input.

Comment: Sounds like your compiler doesn't comply with the C language standard -- C requires the compiler to promote `unsigned char` to `unsigned int` when passed as the arguments to variadic functions like `printf`.

Comment: Two obvious things to check. 1. Do you have stdio.h included, and get the right prototype for printf ? 2. Do you have a prototype for hex_char_to_int() before you're calling it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, that code should work under any conforming C compiler.

I haven't used Keil C51, but I've seen some indications that it doesn't entirely follow the requirements of the C standard, for example in promoting narrow types.

(This answer previously included a number of possible suggestions, most of which didn't pan out. If you're curious, see the edit history.)

Apparently an `unsigned char` argument passed to `printf` is *not* promoted to `int` or `unsigned int`, as the c standard requires.

To work around this while keeping your code reasonably portable, add casts to explicitly convert the values of `foo` and `bar` to `unsigned int`:

```
printf("foo: %02x, bar: %02x\r\n", (unsigned int)foo, (unsigned int)bar);
```

(The `\r` normally wouldn't be necessary, since `\n` is automatically converted to the system's line ending sequence for text streams, but perhaps Keil C51 works differently.)

Again, it *should* work either way, but this change might work around a <strike>bug</strike> feature of Keil 51.

**UPDATE :**

I just checked the online documentation for Keil C51. The documentation for [printf](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_printf.htm) shows some non-standard features, including `b` and `B` to specify `char` types, just as `l` specifies `long` types.

`b` and `B` are not necessary in standard C, since it's not possible to pass a `char` (or `unsigned char`, or `signed char`) argument to `printf`; any such argument will be promoted to `int`, or possibly `unsigned int`. I infer from this, and from the error you've run into, that Keil C51 doesn't promote narrow arguments to variadic functions, and in particular that an `unsigned char` argument is *not* promoted either to `int` or to `unsigned int`.

That explains why

```
printf("%02x", foo);
```

didn't work, and why

```
printf("%02x", (unsigned int)foo);
```

did.

This compiler targets a small 8-bit microprocessor. It makes sense that you wouldn't want to implicitly widen single-byte arguments. The authors apparently chose performance over conformance -- which is a perfectly valid decision. (It would be nice if the documentation were more explicit about this, or maybe I've missed something.)

Probably the recommended way to print `unsigned char` values in hex would be:

```
printf("foo: %02bx, bar: %02bx\r\n", foo, bar);
```

Note that this is specific to Keil C51, and makes your code non-portable to other platforms. But then again, code written to run on such a small system isn't likely to be portable anyway.

Casting to `unsigned int`, as I suggested previously, should also work, but using `"%02bx"` might be more efficient in time and code size, since the arguments can be passed as single bytes.

Comment: +1, as I almost never suspect a compiler bug as a feature :-)

Comment: @jxh More like warnings are not enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately making this change only resulted in different gibberish :(

Comment: @Drew: I've added another couple of ideas. What is `sizeof (unsigned int)`?

Comment: @KeithThompson I tried changing the text in the `printf` and it works now. I'd still like to know the root cause if possible but the problem is fixed at least. `sizeof(unsigned int)` is 2 on this chip.

Comment: My guess is that it's a bug in the compiler, specifically in the way it promotes arguments to variadic functions, not in `printf`. Try these: `unsigned char uc = 'x'; printf("0x%x\n", (unsigned int)uc); printf("0x%x\n", uc);` (or replace `\n` by `\r\n` if your system requires it).

Comment: Accepted. Its definitely a pain that I can't use my usual C documentation, but at least now I know. Thank you!

Comment: Fascinating.  I don't think that I've ever seen a C compiler intentionally deviate from the language standard quite like this before.  But as you said, since it's targeting an 8-bit microprocessor, there could supposedly be valid performance reasons for doing so.